# How do I set the icon and splash screen for a Cordova app in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013, icons, splash-screen

I am trying to make a Cordova application inside Visual Studio 2013 Professional. When I add a `<icon>` tag to my config.xml as well as a `<splash>` tag, the icon does not actually show up when I run my app.

My icon image is .png format and 128x128.
Here is the relevant section in my config.xml:

```
<icon src="res/icon.png"/>
<splash src="images/about.jpg"/>
```

Can anyone help me? I can post more code if that is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS Tools for Apache Cordova in VS 2013, you need to provide visual assets with names and dimensions listed in this documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx).

Our next public release of VS 2015 will support using config.xml to configure visual assets as in your sample.

Comment: Does VS Tools for Apache Cordova in VS 2013 support splash screens for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ and if so what should they be named?

Comment: Yes.  We added the following images to support the new iPhones:
Icon-60-3x.png, Screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png, Screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png, Screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png.
Using these names and dimensions with your own images should work.

Comment: @Ellen. Using VS 2013 Cordova Tools latest version, my iOS apps do not display the given splashscreen and icons unless I set <icon> and <splashscreen> elements in config.xml. However, when config.xml is edited using the visual editor, it simply deletes all <icon> and <splashscreen> elements. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for this tip for VS 2013, however I did add app store wide icons for Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png, and Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png to the res/icons/windows/ folder, but the app store listing shows a very ugly stretched smaller logo from the bundle. All other icons are fine, could you suggest what is wrong with the wide icons? The app is Holiday Search Engine in the Windows 8.1 app store.

Comment: For VS2015 see: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Visual Studio Cordova will not, without adding a 3rd party hook which requires advanced configuration, allow you to change them.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual studio

Step 1. Install Splash Screen Plugin from config.xml

Step 2. Change images for splash screens (The res\screens\platform subfolder contains splash screens for each platform).

Step 3. Run Project on Device.